# How to view Chrome's cached web page?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I visited a webpage but now the webpage has been removed or the server is down.  I assume that Chrome has cached a version of this webpage.  If so, how can I view this webpage?

Comment: FYI Windows 10 Chrome cache is stored at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache. The files will have no extension, but you can still open them in a text editor

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1316540/where-has-chrome-cache-been-moved-to) is what you are looking for in 2020

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Type `chrome://cache` in the address bar to get a list of resources cached by Chrome.

Unfortunately, clicking on a resource shows a HEX+ASCII preview of its contents. 
In cases when the content is gzipped (archived) this preview cannot be read, unless processed with a tool that can decompress it.

Comment: Which tool could be used here?

Comment: I don't know if such a tool exists, but theoretically it could be possible to make one, since the binary contents of the file can be accessed (in a strange format, it's true)

Comment: after a Google search I found this article: http://www.frozax.com/blog/2011/05/recover-file-google-chrome-cache-gzipped/ I haven't tried it, but looks promising.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos: I created a tool that works online, see my [answer](http://superuser.com/a/575410) below.

Comment: The HTTP header fields are listed at the top of the page, before the Hex view of the contents, even if the contents of the file are zipped.  This is what I need.

Comment: It's not working now; [they removed it lately](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=811956).

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1316540/where-has-chrome-cache-been-moved-to) is what you are looking for in 2020

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the site and what it is, Google itself should have a cached version of it, if their crawler has been on it, that is.

Just try to Google the site, and see if you can find it there. If you find it, hover the mouse over the name and an arrow should become visible on the right. Clicking on it will bring up a link to the cached version of the website.

[image: cached version - Google]

Answer (score 2):

If you need something that doesn't necessarily exist in your browser cache, or say you want to see an older version, you should check out [The Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) aka the Internet Archive.  It has been a great source of help to me on numerous occasions.  I use it for doing research into MMO history to understand old rule sets, patch notes, etc.  Just punch in the url for the site and it'll show you the snapshots it has on record.

Comment: Ironically I'm currently trying to load an Internet Archive page from cache because [The Internet Archive is down as I type this](https://twitter.com/internetarchive/status/1562637688918142976).

Answer (score 1):

**Most important point: Browser caches are volatile and old content is aggressively discarded. Your scale of "how soon to act" is measured in minutes to hours.**

Assuming CTRL+F in about:cache finds the URL you're looking for, the script below will attempt to save everything matching that URL. It's completely automated. I wrote this when what.cd went down.

If there is nothing in your cache, congratulations :( you're in "hard" mode. If you *really* want your cache data back you'll need to get TestDisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) working and see if it can recover anything in your cache folder. If the data restores cleanly you might be able to get at it from Chrome, but you may be stuck trying to parse the on-disk format directly. (You may have luck feeding recovered data to the NirSoft cache viewer.)

If you actually have something in about:cache, awesome!!

1. Create two folders somewhere, one called "files" and one called "raw" (or similar names).
2. Open chrome://settings/search#Download%20location
3. Change your downloads folder to the raw folder
4. Open about:cache (leave the settings tab open)
5. Hit F12 to open the devtools (note - ignore any Content Security Policy errors you see the whole time the devtools are open)
6. Copy everything below to your clipboard (make sure you get the gigantic bunch of minified JS at the end, there's an "end of text" comment)
7. Go to the console tab in the devtools
8. Paste, wait for Chrome to catch up, and hit enter.
9. Now you should have two buttons on the cache webpage. Type in the URL string (non-regex for simplicity) that you want to match. Hit the "raw" button and enjoy watching Chrome spazz out. :P
10. Now go switch your downloads folder to the "files" folder, come back and click the "files" button.

<sup>(11. Remember to change your download folder back)</sup>

---

Now you have two folders full of data.

If the script crashed (hopefully not) or printed any "error saving" messages in the devtools when you hit the "files" button, there was a parsing error when it was deobfuscating the files, and you'll need to headscratch your way through the raw versions. This is just a parsing problem and can be fixed by modifying the script but I've no idea all of the responses Chrome can spit back in this scenario.

BEWARE that the raw data includes HTTP header information, and be careful if you're sending it to someone else to help recover it.

One major issue is decompression - I'm using a random gunzip JS library I found online, it may not be perfect (although it should be fine). If it looks like this library crashed or has an issue, comment out the JXG.decompress() line to save the data in gzipped form and see if you can re-inflate it locally.

Another problem is that Chrome will choke when you open your downloads folder because it's dumbly trying to represent the full text of the file you downloaded as a base64 string. Hitting the 'x' on those downloads will prevent that.

Note that this saves forward-slashes as ^ (caret) chars and replaces all other (Windows) prohibited chars with "#" in filenames, in order to capture the full URL in the save filename.

---

Public domain, no ownership. Enhance at will; was built in a couple (3-4) hours (the code is terrible). Only tested on my Linux laptop; there may be bugs :D

Also - lots of kudos to the Stack Exchange team for accepting this 20KB+ post. I decided to take the "don't post links" thing to the extreme. That said, everyone is welcome to run off with this script (and very hopefully improve it!)

```
// CC0 | November 2016 by i336_ (asmqb7@gmail.com)

var ui = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(ui);

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var dl = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(dl);

var list = document.querySelector('table');
var len = list.children[0].childElementCount;
var save_raw, dl_raw, dl_files, status, search, entries, donecount, url, next, save_errors = "";

ui.innerHTML =
    '<div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px; top: 20px; left: 20px; background: #cf0">' +
    '<h2 id="status">Type a string</h2>' +
    '<div><input id="search" /></div><br>' +
    '<button style="display: none" id="dl-files">Download as files</button><br><br>' +
    '<button style="display: none" id="dl-raw">Download raw data</button>' +
    '</div>';

status = document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML;

search = document.querySelector('#search');

dl_files = document.querySelector('#dl-files');

dl_files.onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector('#dl-files').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    dl_files.disabled = dl_raw.disabled = 1;
    donecount = 1;
    save_raw = 0;
    next = len - 1;
    findnext();
}

dl_raw = document.querySelector('#dl-raw');

dl_raw.onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector('#dl-raw').style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    dl_files.disabled = dl_raw.disabled = 1;
    donecount = 1;
    save_raw = 1;
    next = len - 1;
    findnext();
}

document.querySelector('#search').oninput = function() {
    url = search.value;
    if (url.length == 0) {
        setstatus('Empty string doesn\'t work');
        return;
    }
    entries = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (list.children[0].children[i].children[0].children[0].href.indexOf(url) > -1) entries++;
    }

    if (entries > 0) {
        setstatus(entries + ' entry(s)!');
        dl_files.style.display = dl_raw.style.display = 'inline-block';
    } else {
        setstatus('No data :\'(');
    }
}
function setstatus(text) {
    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = text;
}
function wait() {
    console.log('waiting');
    var dosave = 0;
    try {
        if (frames[0].document.body.innerHTML.substr(-36) == '</pre><hr><pre></pre><table></table>') dosave = 1;
    } catch (e) { }
    if (dosave) {
        setTimeout(save, 100);
    } else {
        setTimeout(wait, 100);
    }
}
function parse(rawhtml) {
    var lines = Math.ceil(rawhtml.length / 76);
    var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        line = rawhtml.substr(10 + (76 * i), 47);
        for (j = 0; j < line.length; j += 3) {
            str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(line.substr(j, 2), 16));
        }
    }
    if (str.substr(10, 8) == '1f 8b 08') {
        str = JXG.decompress(btoa(str));
    }
    return str;
}
function save() {
    console.log('triggering download');
    dl.download = iframe.src.substr(25).replace(/:\/\//, '___').replace(/\//g, '^').replace(/[\<\>\:\"\\\/\|\?\*]/, '#');
    var dl_data = "";
    var dosave = 0;
    if (save_raw) {
        dl.download = 'raw_' + dl.download;
        dl.href = 'data:text/plain;base64,' + btoa(frames[0].document.body.innerHTML);
        dosave = 1;
    } else {
        try {
            var dl_data = frames[0].document.querySelectorAll('pre')[2].innerText;
            if (dl_data != "") {
                dl.href = 'data:text/plain;base64,' + btoa(parse(dl_data));
                dosave = 1;
            } else {
                console.log('No data while saving: ' + iframe.src, e);
                save_errors += "ERROR: NO DATA WHILE SAVING " + iframe.src + "\n";
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Frame load error while saving: ' + iframe.src, e);
            save_errors += "ERROR: FRAME LOAD ERROR WHILE SAVING " + iframe.src + "\n";
        }
    }
    if (dosave == 1) {
        dl.click();
    }
    frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = "";
    donecount++;
    setTimeout(findnext, 100);
}
function load(index) {
    console.log('loading ' + donecount + ' of ' + entries);
    setstatus('Saving ' + donecount + '/' + entries);
    iframe.src = list.children[0].children[index].children[0].children[0].href;
    setTimeout(wait, 100);
}
function findnext() {
    console.log('findnext');
    s = -1;
    for (i = next; i > -1; i--) {
        if (list.children[0].children[i].children[0].children[0].href.indexOf(url) > -1) {
            s = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (s != -1) {
        load(s);
        next = s - 1;
    } else {
        console.log('done!!');
        if (save_errors != "") console.error(save_errors);
        save_errors = "";
        setstatus((save_raw ? 'Raw data' : 'Files') + ' saved!');
        dl_files.disabled = dl_raw.disabled = 0;
        document.querySelector('#dl-raw').style.fontWeight = document.querySelector('#dl-files').style.fontWeight = 'normal';
    }
}
!function(){var e,r,n;!function(t){function o(e,r){return w.call(e,r)}function i(e,r){var n,t,o,i,u,a,c,f,s,l,p=r&&r.split("/"),h=k.map,d=h&&h["*"]||{};if(e&&"."===e.charAt(0))if(r){for(p=p.slice(0,p.length-1),e=p.concat(e.split("/")),f=0;f<e.length;f+=1)if(l=e[f],"."===l)e.splice(f,1),f-=1;else if(".."===l){if(1===f&&(".."===e[2]||".."===e[0]))break;f>0&&(e.splice(f-1,2),f-=2)}e=e.join("/")}else 0===e.indexOf("./")&&(e=e.substring(2));if((p||d)&&h){for(n=e.split("/"),f=n.length;f>0;f-=1){if(t=n.slice(0,f).join("/"),p)for(s=p.length;s>0;s-=1)if(o=h[p.slice(0,s).join("/")],o&&(o=o[t])){i=o,u=f;break}if(i)break;!a&&d&&d[t]&&(a=d[t],c=f)}!i&&a&&(i=a,u=c),i&&(n.splice(0,u,i),e=n.join("/"))}return e}function u(e,r){return function(){return h.apply(t,C.call(arguments,0).concat([e,r]))}}function a(e){return function(r){return i(r,e)}}function c(e){return function(r){b[e]=r}}function f(e){if(o(m,e)){var r=m[e];delete m[e],y[e]=!0,p.apply(t,r)}if(!o(b,e)&&!o(y,e))throw new Error("No "+e);return b[e]}function s(e){var r,n=e?e.indexOf("!"):-1;return n>-1&&(r=e.substring(0,n),e=e.substring(n+1,e.length)),[r,e]}function l(e){return function(){return k&&k.config&&k.config[e]||{}}}var p,h,d,g,b={},m={},k={},y={},w=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,C=[].slice;d=function(e,r){var n,t=s(e),o=t[0];return e=t[1],o&&(o=i(o,r),n=f(o)),o?e=n&&n.normalize?n.normalize(e,a(r)):i(e,r):(e=i(e,r),t=s(e),o=t[0],e=t[1],o&&(n=f(o))),{f:o?o+"!"+e:e,n:e,pr:o,p:n}},g={require:function(e){return u(e)},exports:function(e){var r=b[e];return"undefined"!=typeof r?r:b[e]={}},module:function(e){return{id:e,uri:"",exports:b[e],config:l(e)}}},p=function(e,r,n,i){var a,s,l,p,h,k,w=[];if(i=i||e,"function"==typeof n){for(r=!r.length&&n.length?["require","exports","module"]:r,h=0;h<r.length;h+=1)if(p=d(r[h],i),s=p.f,"require"===s)w[h]=g.require(e);else if("exports"===s)w[h]=g.exports(e),k=!0;else if("module"===s)a=w[h]=g.module(e);else if(o(b,s)||o(m,s)||o(y,s))w[h]=f(s);else{if(!p.p)throw new Error(e+" missing "+s);p.p.load(p.n,u(i,!0),c(s),{}),w[h]=b[s]}l=n.apply(b[e],w),e&&(a&&a.exports!==t&&a.exports!==b[e]?b[e]=a.exports:l===t&&k||(b[e]=l))}else e&&(b[e]=n)},e=r=h=function(e,r,n,o,i){return"string"==typeof e?g[e]?g[e](r):f(d(e,r).f):(e.splice||(k=e,r.splice?(e=r,r=n,n=null):e=t),r=r||function(){},"function"==typeof n&&(n=o,o=i),o?p(t,e,r,n):setTimeout(function(){p(t,e,r,n)},4),h)},h.config=function(e){return k=e,k.deps&&h(k.deps,k.callback),h},n=function(e,r,n){r.splice||(n=r,r=[]),o(b,e)||o(m,e)||(m[e]=[e,r,n])},n.amd={jQuery:!0}}(),n("../node_modules/almond/almond",function(){}),n("jxg",[],function(){var e={};return"object"!=typeof JXG||JXG.extend||(e=JXG),e.extend=function(e,r,n,t){var o,i;n=n||!1,t=t||!1;for(o in r)(!n||n&&r.hasOwnProperty(o))&&(i=t?o.toLowerCase():o,e[i]=r[o])},e.extend(e,{boards:{},readers:{},elements:{},registerElement:function(e,r){e=e.toLowerCase(),this.elements[e]=r},registerReader:function(e,r){var n,t;for(n=0;n<r.length;n++)t=r[n].toLowerCase(),"function"!=typeof this.readers[t]&&(this.readers[t]=e)},shortcut:function(e,r){return function(){return e[r].apply(this,arguments)}},getRef:function(e,r){return e.select(r)},getReference:function(e,r){return e.select(r)},debugInt:function(){var e,r;for(e=0;e<arguments.length;e++)r=arguments[e],"object"==typeof window&&window.console&&console.log?console.log(r):"object"==typeof document&&document.getElementById("debug")&&(document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML+=r+"<br/>")},debugWST:function(){var r=new Error;e.debugInt.apply(this,arguments),r&&r.stack&&(e.debugInt("stacktrace"),e.debugInt(r.stack.split("\n").slice(1).join("\n")))},debugLine:function(){var r=new Error;e.debugInt.apply(this,arguments),r&&r.stack&&e.debugInt("Called from",r.stack.split("\n").slice(2,3).join("\n"))},debug:function(){e.debugInt.apply(this,arguments)}}),e}),n("utils/zip",["jxg"],function(e){var r=[0,128,64,192,32,160,96,224,16,144,80,208,48,176,112,240,8,136,72,200,40,168,104,232,24,152,88,216,56,184,120,248,4,132,68,196,36,164,100,228,20,148,84,212,52,180,116,244,12,140,76,204,44,172,108,236,28,156,92,220,60,188,124,252,2,130,66,194,34,162,98,226,18,146,82,210,50,178,114,242,10,138,74,202,42,170,106,234,26,154,90,218,58,186,122,250,6,134,70,198,38,166,102,230,22,150,86,214,54,182,118,246,14,142,78,206,46,174,110,238,30,158,94,222,62,190,126,254,1,129,65,193,33,161,97,225,17,145,81,209,49,177,113,241,9,137,73,201,41,169,105,233,25,153,89,217,57,185,121,249,5,133,69,197,37,165,101,229,21,149,85,213,53,181,117,245,13,141,77,205,45,173,109,237,29,157,93,221,61,189,125,253,3,131,67,195,35,163,99,227,19,147,83,211,51,179,115,243,11,139,75,203,43,171,107,235,27,155,91,219,59,187,123,251,7,135,71,199,39,167,103,231,23,151,87,215,55,183,119,247,15,143,79,207,47,175,111,239,31,159,95,223,63,191,127,255],n=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,15,17,19,23,27,31,35,43,51,59,67,83,99,115,131,163,195,227,258,0,0],t=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,0,99,99],o=[1,2,3,4,5,7,9,13,17,25,33,49,65,97,129,193,257,385,513,769,1025,1537,2049,3073,4097,6145,8193,12289,16385,24577],i=[0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13],u=[16,17,18,0,8,7,9,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,13,2,14,1,15],a=256;return e.Util=e.Util||{},e.Util.Unzip=function(c){function f(){return R+=8,O>X?c[X++]:-1}function s(){B=1}function l(){var e;try{return R++,e=1&B,B>>=1,0===B&&(B=f(),e=1&B,B=128|B>>1),e}catch(r){throw r}}function p(e){var n=0,t=e;try{for(;t--;)n=n<<1|l();e&&(n=r[n]>>8-e)}catch(o){throw o}return n}function h(){J=0}function d(e){A++,G[J++]=e,z.push(String.fromCharCode(e)),32768===J&&(J=0)}function g(){this.b0=0,this.b1=0,this.jump=null,this.jumppos=-1}function b(){for(;;){if(M[H]>=x)return-1;if(U[M[H]]===H)return M[H]++;M[H]++}}function m(){var e,r=P[F];if(17===H)return-1;if(F++,H++,e=b(),e>=0)r.b0=e;else if(r.b0=32768,m())return-1;if(e=b(),e>=0)r.b1=e,r.jump=null;else if(r.b1=32768,r.jump=P[F],r.jumppos=F,m())return-1;return H--,0}function k(e,r,n){var t;for(P=e,F=0,U=n,x=r,t=0;17>t;t++)M[t]=0;return H=0,m()?-1:0}function y(e){for(var r,n,t,o=0,i=e[o];;)if(t=l()){if(!(32768&i.b1))return i.b1;for(i=i.jump,r=e.length,n=0;r>n;n++)if(e[n]===i){o=n;break}}else{if(!(32768&i.b0))return i.b0;o++,i=e[o]}}function w(){var a,c,b,m,w,C,v,A,j,U,x,S,z,I,E,L,O;do if(a=l(),b=p(2),0===b)for(s(),U=f(),U|=f()<<8,S=f(),S|=f()<<8,65535&(U^~S)&&e.debug("BlockLen checksum mismatch\n");U--;)c=f(),d(c);else if(1===b)for(;;)if(w=r[p(7)]>>1,w>23?(w=w<<1|l(),w>199?(w-=128,w=w<<1|l()):(w-=48,w>143&&(w+=136))):w+=256,256>w)d(w);else{if(256===w)break;for(w-=257,j=p(t[w])+n[w],w=r[p(5)]>>3,i[w]>8?(x=p(8),x|=p(i[w]-8)<<8):x=p(i[w]),x+=o[w],w=0;j>w;w++)c=G[32767&J-x],d(c)}else if(2===b){for(v=new Array(320),I=257+p(5),E=1+p(5),L=4+p(4),w=0;19>w;w++)v[w]=0;for(w=0;L>w;w++)v[u[w]]=p(3);for(j=q.length,m=0;j>m;m++)q[m]=new g;if(k(q,19,v,0))return h(),1;for(z=I+E,m=0,O=-1;z>m;)if(O++,w=y(q),16>w)v[m++]=w;else if(16===w){if(w=3+p(2),m+w>z)return h(),1;for(C=m?v[m-1]:0;w--;)v[m++]=C}else{if(w=17===w?3+p(3):11+p(7),m+w>z)return h(),1;for(;w--;)v[m++]=0}for(j=T.length,m=0;j>m;m++)T[m]=new g;if(k(T,I,v,0))return h(),1;for(j=T.length,m=0;j>m;m++)q[m]=new g;for(A=[],m=I;m<v.length;m++)A[m-I]=v[m];if(k(q,E,A,0))return h(),1;for(;;)if(w=y(T),w>=256){if(w-=256,0===w)break;for(w-=1,j=p(t[w])+n[w],w=y(q),i[w]>8?(x=p(8),x|=p(i[w]-8)<<8):x=p(i[w]),x+=o[w];j--;)c=G[32767&J-x],d(c)}else d(w)}while(!a);return h(),s(),0}function C(){var e,r,n,t,o,i,u,c,s=[];try{if(z=[],L=!1,s[0]=f(),s[1]=f(),120===s[0]&&218===s[1]&&(w(),E[I]=[z.join(""),"geonext.gxt"],I++),31===s[0]&&139===s[1]&&(S(),E[I]=[z.join(""),"file"],I++),80===s[0]&&75===s[1]&&(L=!0,s[2]=f(),s[3]=f(),3===s[2]&&4===s[3])){for(s[0]=f(),s[1]=f(),v=f(),v|=f()<<8,c=f(),c|=f()<<8,f(),f(),f(),f(),u=f(),u|=f()<<8,u|=f()<<16,u|=f()<<24,i=f(),i|=f()<<8,i|=f()<<16,i|=f()<<24,o=f(),o|=f()<<8,o|=f()<<16,o|=f()<<24,t=f(),t|=f()<<8,n=f(),n|=f()<<8,e=0,N=[];t--;)r=f(),"/"===r|":"===r?e=0:a-1>e&&(N[e++]=String.fromCharCode(r));for(j||(j=N),e=0;n>e;)r=f(),e++;A=0,8===c&&(w(),E[I]=new Array(2),E[I][0]=z.join(""),E[I][1]=N.join(""),I++),S()}}catch(l){throw l}}var v,A,j,U,x,S,z=[],I=0,E=[],G=new Array(32768),J=0,L=!1,O=c.length,X=0,B=1,R=0,T=new Array(288),q=new Array(32),F=0,P=null,H=(new Array(64),new Array(64),0),M=new Array(17),N=[];M[0]=0,S=function(){var e,r,n,t,o,i,u=[];if(8&v&&(u[0]=f(),u[1]=f(),u[2]=f(),u[3]=f(),80===u[0]&&75===u[1]&&7===u[2]&&8===u[3]?(e=f(),e|=f()<<8,e|=f()<<16,e|=f()<<24):e=u[0]|u[1]<<8|u[2]<<16|u[3]<<24,r=f(),r|=f()<<8,r|=f()<<16,r|=f()<<24,n=f(),n|=f()<<8,n|=f()<<16,n|=f()<<24),L&&C(),u[0]=f(),8===u[0]){if(v=f(),f(),f(),f(),f(),f(),t=f(),4&v)for(u[0]=f(),u[2]=f(),H=u[0]+256*u[1],o=0;H>o;o++)f();if(8&v)for(o=0,N=[],i=f();i;)("7"===i||":"===i)&&(o=0),a-1>o&&(N[o++]=i),i=f();if(16&v)for(i=f();i;)i=f();2&v&&(f(),f()),w(),e=f(),e|=f()<<8,e|=f()<<16,e|=f()<<24,n=f(),n|=f()<<8,n|=f()<<16,n|=f()<<24,L&&C()}},e.Util.Unzip.prototype.unzipFile=function(e){var r;for(this.unzip(),r=0;r<E.length;r++)if(E[r][1]===e)return E[r][0];return""},e.Util.Unzip.prototype.unzip=function(){return C(),E}},e.Util}),n("utils/encoding",["jxg"],function(e){var r=0,n=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,10,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,3,11,6,6,6,5,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,0,12,24,36,60,96,84,12,12,12,48,72,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,0,12,12,12,12,12,0,12,0,12,12,12,24,12,12,12,12,12,24,12,24,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,24,12,12,12,12,12,24,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,24,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,36,12,36,12,12,12,36,12,12,12,12,12,36,12,36,12,12,12,36,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12];return e.Util=e.Util||{},e.Util.UTF8={encode:function(e){var r,n,t="",o=e.length;if(e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n"),"function"==typeof unescape&&"function"==typeof encodeURIComponent)return unescape(encodeURIComponent(e));for(r=0;o>r;r++)n=e.charCodeAt(r),128>n?t+=String.fromCharCode(n):n>127&&2048>n?(t+=String.fromCharCode(192|n>>6),t+=String.fromCharCode(128|63&n)):(t+=String.fromCharCode(224|n>>12),t+=String.fromCharCode(128|63&n>>6),t+=String.fromCharCode(128|63&n));return t},decode:function(e){var t,o,i,u=0,a=0,c=r,f=[],s=e.length,l=[];for(t=0;s>t;t++)o=e.charCodeAt(t),i=n[o],a=c!==r?63&o|a<<6:255>>i&o,c=n[256+c+i],c===r&&(a>65535?f.push(55232+(a>>10),56320+(1023&a)):f.push(a),u++,0===u%1e4&&(l.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,f)),f=[]));return l.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,f)),l.join("")},asciiCharCodeAt:function(e,r){var n=e.charCodeAt(r);if(n>255)switch(n){case 8364:n=128;break;case 8218:n=130;break;case 402:n=131;break;case 8222:n=132;break;case 8230:n=133;break;case 8224:n=134;break;case 8225:n=135;break;case 710:n=136;break;case 8240:n=137;break;case 352:n=138;break;case 8249:n=139;break;case 338:n=140;break;case 381:n=142;break;case 8216:n=145;break;case 8217:n=146;break;case 8220:n=147;break;case 8221:n=148;break;case 8226:n=149;break;case 8211:n=150;break;case 8212:n=151;break;case 732:n=152;break;case 8482:n=153;break;case 353:n=154;break;case 8250:n=155;break;case 339:n=156;break;case 382:n=158;break;case 376:n=159}return n}},e.Util.UTF8}),n("utils/base64",["jxg","utils/encoding"],function(e,r){function n(e,r){return 255&e.charCodeAt(r)}function t(e,r){var n=o.indexOf(e.charAt(r));if(-1===n)throw new Error("JSXGraph/utils/base64: Can't decode string (invalid character).");return n}var o="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",i="=";return e.Util=e.Util||{},e.Util.Base64={encode:function(e){var t,u,a,c,f,s=[];for(f=r.encode(e),a=f.length,c=a%3,t=0;a-c>t;t+=3)u=n(f,t)<<16|n(f,t+1)<<8|n(f,t+2),s.push(o.charAt(u>>18),o.charAt(63&u>>12),o.charAt(63&u>>6),o.charAt(63&u));switch(c){case 1:u=n(f,a-1),s.push(o.charAt(u>>2),o.charAt(63&u<<4),i,i);break;case 2:u=n(f,a-2)<<8|n(f,a-1),s.push(o.charAt(u>>10),o.charAt(63&u>>4),o.charAt(63&u<<2),i)}return s.join("")},decode:function(e,n){var o,u,a,c,f,s,l=[],p=[];if(o=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/=]/g,""),a=o.length,0!==a%4)throw new Error("JSXGraph/utils/base64: Can't decode string (invalid input length).");for(o.charAt(a-1)===i&&(c=1,o.charAt(a-2)===i&&(c=2),a-=4),u=0;a>u;u+=4)f=t(o,u)<<18|t(o,u+1)<<12|t(o,u+2)<<6|t(o,u+3),p.push(f>>16,255&f>>8,255&f),0===u%1e4&&(l.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,p)),p=[]);switch(c){case 1:f=t(o,a)<<12|t(o,a+1)<<6|t(o,a+2),p.push(f>>10,255&f>>2);break;case 2:f=t(o,u)<<6|t(o,u+1),p.push(f>>4)}return l.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,p)),s=l.join(""),n&&(s=r.decode(s)),s},decodeAsArray:function(e){var r,n=this.decode(e),t=[],o=n.length;for(r=0;o>r;r++)t[r]=n.charCodeAt(r);return t}},e.Util.Base64}),n("../build/compressor.deps.js",["jxg","utils/zip","utils/base64"],function(e,r,n){return e.decompress=function(e){return unescape(new r.Unzip(n.decodeAsArray(e)).unzip()[0][0])},e}),window.JXG=r("../build/compressor.deps.js")}();
console.log('ready');

// If you can see this you've copied the whole thing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just prefix the url with `cache:` and it will load the latest google cache on chrome.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work now :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Chrome 60.0.3163.49 (beta, Aug 2017) to display cache content with the Show Saved Copy feature.

1. Turn on the Chrome flag [Show Saved Copy (click here)](http://chrome://flags/#show-saved-copy).
   Select 'Enable Primary' - I didn't test Secondary
   Relaunch Chrome with the button at the bottom.  This will refresh all your Chrome windows.

If you have any tabs which are disconnected (site not available now), these may not refresh correctly with the Relaunch, most will.  Use right click SaveAs .htm to save a local copy before the Relaunch.  In particular, if you have multiple tabs which are historic snapshots of the same page but with different historic content, they will all refresh with the latest snapshot.

2. Turn on Airplane mode or physically disconnect from your network.
   The Show Saved Copy feature only works when the site is fully disconnected.  If it's slow to respond and times out with Err_Connection_Timed_Out, the Show Saved Copy button isn't displayed.
3. Open the Chrome Cache list [chrome://cache/](http://chrome://cache/)
   You'll see a long list of URL links to cached page files.
   Use Ctrl-F to find the one you're looking for.
   Highlight and copy the one you want.

Getting the exact URL from the cache list is only necessary if you want to display a specific file from the cache, otherwise any link to the page should pull from cache.

4. Open a New Tab tab.
5. Paste the copied URL into the address box, press enter.
   The page load will fail with a No Internet error, and at the bottom
   you should see a 'Show Saved Copy' button.
6. Click 'Show Saved Copy' which will display the cached page content but styles and formatting may not be correctly applied.
7. Use the Back and Forward arrows to recover formatting.
   Back returns to the New Tab page.
   Forward returns to your cached page.  If the styling and format is still in cache, when your page redraws, it will paint with the full format.

As i336 notes, cache is volatile.  The sooner you try to recover cache content, the better your chances are.

The Show Saved Copy feature has been posted on the web since Dec. 2012 and in tech news as recently as May 2015 ([here CNet](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/load-cached-pages-when-offline-in-chrome/) and [here PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2927447/how-to-view-recent-webpages-when-youre-offline.html)), but were not mentioned in this Superuser thread (originated Apr. 2012). When combined with Airplane mode and the exact URL from the Chrome cache list, it provides a straightforward way to display specific cache files.

The Senseful and i336 javascript tools may work, but failed for me. I presume they need mods to accommodate the specific web layout used for my pages.  Using Show Saved Copy avoids the javascript version dependency.

Answer (score -4):

When you do a Google search, you will see a triangle at the end of the green colored line - click on the triangle and you will a "cached" option. Click that to get Google's cached page.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked; the OP is asking about how to view _Chrome's_ cache and not _Google's_. -1