# Is there a way to see when Chrome last downloaded a cached file?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

Like other browsers, Chrome will store files (images, javascript, etc.) so that they don't need to be downloaded on each visit to a website.

For a given file, is there a way to see in Chrome when (time & date) that file was last retrieved from the server?

For clarity: I know that clicking on the page icon, and looking in the connection tab will show "site information" with the date that the file was first retrieved. I am after the most recent occasion, not the first occasion.

Comment: Please update your question rather than include info in a comment - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the address bar type `chrome://cache`. It will show a long list of files in your cache (the find... tool is your friend here). Clicking on one of the file names will bring up detailed information for the cached file, including the time & date it was last retrieved from the server (in Greenwich Mean Time).

Tested in Chromium. See also: [How to view Chrome's cached web page?](https://superuser.com/questions/411506/how-to-view-chromes-cached-web-page)

Comment: Unfortunately the URL has been removed. Check [this](https://superuser.com/a/1319699/1336128)