# Where has chrome://cache been moved to?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

In the past it was possible to browse the browser cache by visiting `chrome://cache/` but it seems to have been (re)moved?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but NirSoft [ChromeCacheView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) and [ImageCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/image_cache_viewer.html) may be of interest.

Comment: Unfortunately those only work on Windows.

Comment: Worked for me, but then I updated to latest version to be sure, and poof, its gone.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

#### It was removed on purpose and it won't be coming back.

Both `chrome://cache` and `chrome://view-http-cache` have been removed starting chrome 66.  They work in version 65.

#### Workaround

You can check the `chrome://chrome-urls/` for complete list of internal Chrome URLs.

The only workaround that comes into my mind is to use `menu/more tools/developer tools` and having a `Network` tab selected.

#### The reason why it was removed is this bug:

- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/6ebc11f6f6d112e4cca5251d4c0203e18cd79adc
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=811956

#### The discussion:

- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/net-dev/YNct7Nk6bd8/ODeGPq6KAAAJ

Comment: Well that sucks. :(

Is there a workaround for a user loading a page while offline?

Comment: @lowcrawler not I know of.  I suppose, Google wants you to be always connected.

Comment: @tucan wasn't it to mainstream [service workers usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker)?

Comment: The links provided do not explain in any way why this was removed. It seems to be a very useful feature, removed for no reason.

Comment: @krubo did you actually read the links?  If you would do so there you find a discussion e.g. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/net-dev/YNct7Nk6bd8/ODeGPq6KAAAJ

Comment: @tukan I read that one. Their consensus seems to be that they themselves rarely use it, and that most people who need it can use "cachetool" instead, which isn't further explained. When I saw "the reason why it was removed is this bug" in this answer I was expecting to read about a security issue or something, not just that the developers don't think it's useful.

Comment: @krubo Who decides what will be in the application?  The developers.  In their eye an unused feature is a security risk because there maybe bugs hidden as the code is frequently used - a bug.

Comment: can you or someone else please elaborate on the work around?

Comment: @tukan The developers do "decide what will be in the application" in order to meet the users' needs. Here it's clearly NOT the case, they're against the users' needs.

Comment: @maxxyme Actually not, the developers listen to the company that pays them - most of the google?  If you have any complain try it there, I don't think they will listen.  The ordinary users do not need this - the web and other kind of developers do.

Answer (score 19):

It hasn't been moved, it's been *re*moved! Because of the Bug: [811956, 809823](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/6ebc11f6f6d112e4cca5251d4c0203e18cd79adc)

However the cache still exists and is at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Cache`.

You can view/list your cache using a [Cache viewer for Google Chrome](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html)!

Comment: On macos the path seems to be `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Application\ Cache`

Comment: I get `no such file or directory `