# How to make windows task scheduler work UTC and ignore current local timezone?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a task to run at 5 minutes past midnight UTC every morning.

My computer automatically adjusts for daylight saving time, so during the winter I have the task scheduled for 00:05:00, and when the clocks go forward to BST (British Summer Time) I have to remember to alter the task to run at 01:05:00. I'm using task scheduler 1.0 on windows 10 pro.

Ok, so I only I have to remember this change twice a year, but it's really annoying that I can't find anyway to do this automatically.

UPDATE - one of the issues with a problem like this is that the live task is only run once a day, and the timezones only change twice a year, so creating a suitable test environment isn't very easy. I've tried the 'synchronise across time zones' button and it doesn't seem to do much, I think it's for running multiple jobs across different servers in different time zones.

Comment: I *think* you solve this by using the **synchronize across timezones** option.

Comment: According to https://superuser.com/questions/1316540/where-has-chrome-cache-been-moved-to, the `synchronize across time zones` option will launch the task as if Standard Time was in effect all year. That is, it will ignore Summer Time, which seems to be what you are seeking.

Comment: @DougDeden - What does Chrome have to do with the author's question?

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm, I have no idea -- I must have pasted the wrong link. Very strange. I'll see if I can find the link I meant to paste.

Comment: This is the link I was trying to point to: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/883b4f47-5b0b-43cc-8e24-9c48867114d6/synchronizing-scheduled-task-across-time-zones?forum=winserverManagement It indicates that the `synchronize across time zones` option will launch the task as if Standard Time was in effect all year. That is, it will ignore Summer Time, which seems to be what the OP is seeking. Yet, it sounds like they've tried that, and it didn't help.

Comment: And this -- https://serverfault.com/a/554761/450038 -- also supports the idea that `synchronize across time zones` should make your task run using UTC, ignoring local time and also ignoring summer time. But yeah, it's hard to test.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this answer doesn't explain how to get your tasks to schedule on a fixed UTC time but it might explain why you may need to look for a third party task scheduler. Windows task scheduler does not properly support summer time changes. SVR2012 didn't, SVR2016 didn't and SVR2019 definately doesn't. With SVR2016 you can set the 'run missed task option' to get around it, but SVR2019 doesn't work even if you set the option. With SVR2019 once BST change has occured, it seems all scheduled tasks for the next 24 hours are disabled and a reboot of windows is required to enable them immediately.

- update *
  server 2019 v1809 ( os build 17763.2237 ) may have fixed task scheduler.