# How to test 'synchronise across time zones' in windows scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task to start at 5 past midnight every morning UTC (aka GMT or greenwich mean time).

I posted [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1419578/how-to-make-windows-task-scheduler-work-utc-and-ignore-current-local-timezone) question over a year ago, the proposed answers resolved around 'synchronise across time zones'. I'm still not sure exactly what this is supposed to do, but it made no difference to the actual start time of my task.

The original question still stands, this post is a slightly different one - how do I test changes involving daylight saving, without just waiting six months for the clock to change again?

Comment: If you can un-sync your machine from an NTP time source, can you set the date/time to something just before the changeover and watch what happens as you approach the DST changeover? Or use an isolated virtual machine?

Comment: @DougDeden - If I unsync from a NTP time source, won't that mean that my computer won't switch to/from Daylight saving time? Or is daylight saving hard-coded from some internal calendar?

Comment: It should still switch. All the NTP source tells you is UTC. Your local machine then gets to decide how to display that to the user, and if/when to change by an hour for DST.